# Laravel reverse pagination order

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel default pagination.

Currently I am displaying the images like this:

```
$images = Image::where('parent_id', null)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(99);
```

Is it possible to reverse the current default pagination order of

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

to

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

I would like the end page be numbered to be '1'

Comment: Well, it may be possible but I think it is complex. Why do you need to "invert" the order of the pages? There is no paginator that goes backwards... Why do you need to do that? Why don't you reverse the order (do `orderBy('created_at')` instead of `desc`). And, by the way, that is `latest()` or `oldest()`.

Comment: If I do 'asc' or lastest()' the newest image would be not shown first.

Comment: Well, do the inverse....

Comment: You do understand that your page1 will always have a floating list of items as your newest page (6 in this example) has to be fully populared.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to create your own paginatore these information might help you.
Output json from paginator is like this:

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

And now you can use these data to create your own paginatore like this:

```
{{ $paginator->links('your file name should be here like this :view.name', [your data is here]) }}
```

However, the easiest way to customize the pagination views is by exporting it to `resources/views/vendor` directory by using this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This command will place the views in the `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory

Comment: This is a good solution, but I would strongly suggest to not do it, as Laravel already has a Paginator and no paginator ever goes backwards... this means there is something wrong, so I would recommend to not do it, but of course, anyone can do whatever they please

Comment: I agree this is unusual to create a paginatore which goes back ward but its not our decision and i say the way which can help to create a custom paginatore